# Chrome.runtime.connect no longer identified?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime

I have an extension with a background page and a sandbox page where most of the content scripts execute.

Whenever I need to do an Ajax call it has to run in the background environment as otherwise I get a CORS error. Recently as of last week I believe, the *chrome.runtime* is no longer available in the sandbox environment for some reason. I can't find any notes etc about it and trying to figure out a solution how to communicate with background page now.

I had this in the sandbox environment to initialize a connect port to pass messages from an Ajax request

```
var ajaxCall = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "ajaxCall"});
```

Is there any info out there that I'm missing on why this change occurred and what are some possible workarounds?

Here's the output for chrome. 1st is the background page and 2nd is the sandbox. They used to be identical in both.

[image: chrome.runtime]

Comment: A sandbox environment refers to the special [sandbox pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandbox), while you seem to refer to content scripts environment where the term sandbox is not used, in which case it's probably https://crbug.com/835287 - chrome.runtime is no longer exposed on HTTP pages.

Comment: My apologies I mixed the 2 up, content scripts aside the scripts in the sandbox are the ones having the issue. So thanks for pointing me to the chrome bug page. It does say NextAction: 2018-04-30 am I correct in assuming that it will be fixed or should I be looking at re-writing the extension?

Comment: The way I read it, the change was intended. I doubt they'll revoke it.